# std::function assignment has no effect in Visual C++ 2015 Win32 Application

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's my scenario:

main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> OnPrepare;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst, HINSTANCE preInst, TCHAR*, int) {
    if (OnPrepare) {
        OnPrepare();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp

```
#define _AFXDLL
#include <afx.h>  // TRACE
#include <functional>

extern std::function<void()> OnPrepare;

class Init {
public:
    Init() {
        OnPrepare = []() {
            TRACE("hello, world!\n");
        };
    }
};

Init g_init;
```

This code does not work in a Win32 application, but works well in a Console application. I don't know why. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code? If I can't do it like this, is there a better way?

EDIT:

`OnPrepare` is always null in a Win32 application, so no `"hello, world"` will appear.

Comment: What do you mean by _can not work_?

Comment: The code can demonstrate this problem. _can not work_ means OnPrepare has not be called.

Comment: The order of initialization of objects with static storage duration at global scope is unspecified.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I found it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for constructing`g_init` modifies `OnPrepare`. This is, of course, only legal if `OnPrepare` has already been constructed. But what if `g_init` is constructed before `OnPrepare`? Then you'll be modifying an object that hasn't been constructed yet and then later constructing an object you've already modified. Ouch. Doing real work in the constructors of static objects is never a good idea.

It's not clear what your outer problem is, but this code isn't a good way to solve it. An ugly workaround is to replace your global `std::function` with a global function that returns a reference to a function static `std::function` and use that. That ensures the object is constructed before being assigned to.

```
std::function<void()>& getOnPrepare()
{
    static std::function<void()> OnPrepare;
    return OnPrepare;
}
```

Then the constructor of `Init` can call `getOnPrepare`, ensuring that `OnPrepare` is constructed before it's assigned to:

```
Init() {
    getOnPrepare() = []() {
        TRACE("hello, world!\n");
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the problem, my assignment run before the constructor. your solution is very well too.

Comment: Another solution is to simply replace the `std::function` with an ordinary `void (*)()` function pointer, which doesn't require construction.  A *non-capturing* lambda can be assigned to a function pointer.